# Rails 4 - Combining activerecord relation results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_games, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :user_games
  has_many :guests, :dependent => :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_games, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :games, :through => :user_games
end

class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :user
end
```

A game can have multiple users and a user can belong to multiple games. A user can also bring guests to a game and I need to keep track of the user who is bringing the guest. I'm trying to figure out the way to create a join where I have a combined list of users and guests attending a game sorted by created_at. The result in the view would be something like:

1. Joe
2. Joe's Guest [link to delete if current_user is Joe]
3. Tom
4. Bill
5. Tom's Guest [link to delete if current_user is Joe]

My first attempt at solving this was adding this in Game:

```
def all_players
  (self.user_games + self.guests).sort_by(&:created_at)
end
```

Iterating on this array in the view becomes clunky because turns it into an Array instead of an ActiveRecord relation. As a result, I got stuck on adding the delete link and I figure there must be a smarter way to go about what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:
Actually this just turned out to be a routing issue with my delete link. My solution seems to be working out ok although it still feels like I could be doing this in a more efficient manner.

Comment: Can you clarify how creating the delete link for an Array element is more clunky than for an AR relation element?

Comment: use [joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables).

Comment: edited original - turned out to just be a routing issue